# How to break line in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Please let me know how to break line in JavaScript.

```
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' 
onClick="parent.location='mailto:er.saurav123@gmail.com?subject=Thanks for writing to me &body=I will get back to you soon. Thanks and Regards Saurav Kumar'">
```

I want a break line in Subject. The output I need is:

```
I will get back to you soon
Thanks and Regards
Saurav Kumar
```

Comment: `%0d%0a` is very intereting.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Add `%0D%0A` to any place you want to encode a line break on the URL.

- `%0D` is a carriage return character
- `%0A` is a line break character

This is the new line sequence on windows machines, though not the same on linux and macs, should work in both.

If you want a linebreak in actual javascript, use the `\n` escape sequence.

---

```
onClick="parent.location='mailto:er.saurav123@gmail.com?subject=Thanks for writing to me &body=I will get back to you soon.%0D%0AThanks and Regards%0D%0ASaurav Kumar'
```

Comment: @saurav2109 - Add an additional `%0D%0A` for every linebreak.

Comment: @oded:Thanks a lot. I have one more query. I have one HTML page with 2 text box, 1 dropdown and 1 button, on button click I want to open the email(as currently I am doing with javascript) with subject line as whatever is selected in the drop down and whatever is written in text box.

Comment: I want the subject should be: Number | Unit | Dropdown Selected value. Please have a look at the code below

Comment: @Oded: Yes, Please help in this aspect

Comment: @saurav2109 - Please ask a new question for this. Comments are not a place for asking new questions.

Comment: <body>
<form id='sampleform' method='post' action='' >Emp Number: <input type='text' name='empnum' /></p><p>Unit Name: <input type='text' name='unit' /></p><p>Type of subscription you want:<p> <select name="type"> <option value="standard">Standard - /option><option value="prof">Professional - Paid</option></select></p></p><p>  
<input type='submit'name='Submit'value='Submit'"parent.location='mailto:er.saurav1@gmail.com?Subject=Thanks for writing &body=Hi,%0A%0CThanks for writing. We will get back to you soon. %0A%0C%0D%0AThanks and Regards,%0A%0CSaurav Kumar'">
</p></form></body>

Comment: @saurav2109 - I will say it one last time. I will not answer this new question here. **ask a new question**.

Answer (score 22):

Here you are ;-)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hello there.\nI am on a second line ;-)")
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

I was facing the same problem. For my solution, I added `br` enclosed between 2 brackets < > enclosed in double quotation marks, and preceded and followed by the + sign:

`+"<br>"+`

Try this in your browser and see, it certainly works in my Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 10):

```
alert("I will get back to you soon\nThanks and Regards\nSaurav Kumar");
```

or use `%0D%0A` in a url

Comment: %0D%0A is single line break, how to make 2 line break

Comment: You just repeat it twice: `%0D%0A%0D%0A`.

Answer (score -1):

Using `+ "<br>" +` between each point you want to break may work for you.

e.g.

```js
var numberTimes = 5;

for(var times = 0; times < numberTimes; times++) {
    document.write("Number of times executed: " + times + " " + "<br>");
}

document.write("It's over.")
```

Comment: It won't. Pay attention to the context of the question. It's a URL not HTML.