# Is there a handwriting like effect plugin in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fonts, html5-canvas, effects

I am a student wanting to create a dashboard for my freshman class.  And to make it more fancier I want to use a handwriting effect.  Let me explain.

Let's say I have the text: "Probability and The Concept of Prediction."  When the page is loaded I want that text to appear as if it's being written on the page as it's being viewed.

Am I crazy to think this is possible or is there a jquery plugin that I can use?

Comment: Are you talking about a typewriter effect (letters appearing one by one)?

Comment: I think he meant like someone is actually writing right now on the screen

Comment: @christophe.  Yes, something similar or in cursive writing yes.

Comment: I can't think of anything off the top of my head, except maybe some clever `<canvas>` tricks...

Comment: @chanckjh Yes something similar.

Comment: But that's not jQuery, though, and it would take quite a lot of effort to implement. Now, if you wanted a typewriter effect, that's much easier to set up...

Comment: @elliotbonneville Oh ok.  Well I am an amateur so i thought it might be jquery effect.  What do you suggest for the typewriter effect?

Comment: Go here for DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/vCx6W/1/ and here for explanation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074399/what-to-choose-for-typewriter-effect-in-javascript

Comment: As @ElliotBonneville says its hard but you can try overriding drawing function of Kinetic Js Text, obviously using `canvas`. Other option is using `svg` and progressively adding points to a path. Both end up complex!!

Comment: @chanckjh thanks for the find! can i use the same script to load word by word as well?

Comment: @sabithpocker thanks! i guess i have to stick with the effect chanckjh found.

Comment: @chanckjh how can i go about doing that? Because in the fiddle it seems its an entire sentence.  What would i need to modify?

Comment: For some real effect check this out- http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-handwriting/6354107

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a typewriter effect (cf. my comment), you can find jQuery plugins like [this one](http://return-true.com/2011/04/jquery-typewriter-revisited/).

If you mean actually drawing the letters, then it's beyond jQuery basic capabilities and you would need to look at graphing/charting libraries instead.

[edit] Note that it is easy to create a simple typewriter effect in jQuery (or JavaScript) without a plugin, [see a couple examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13461922/how-do-i-make-a-new-line-or-add-html-to-this-javascript-function) (including my live demo). However a plugin will help if you need to deal with html, not just text.