# How to insert a line break in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

im creating a bot for my discord server and am attempting to log messages onto a text file. 
I stored all the information i need about the message in a var named logger and am attempting to use node to append my log file.

I tried adding \n to the end of the variable but kept getting a syntax error that pointed to the "\" and said invalid or unexpected token

```
var logger = (message.author.username + "> " + message.content \n)
fs.appendFile('msgs.json', logger, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```

I would like each entry to be on a different line

Comment: `message.content + "\n"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to break line in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768118/how-to-break-line-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

new-line are characters that need to be concatenated onto the end of the string

```
var logger = (message.author.username + "> " + message.content + "\n")
fs.appendFile('msgs.json', logger, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, you need to quote the `\n`, either using double quote, single quote, or `

```
var logger = (message.author.username + "> " + message.content + "\n")
fs.appendFile('msgs.json', logger, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Windows machine.
Try using \r\n instead of just \n.

Honestly, \n is fine; you're probably viewing the log file in notepad or something else that doesn't render non-Windows newlines. Try opening it in a different viewer/editor (e.g. Wordpad).

Use:

```
var logger = (message.author.username + "> " + message.content + '\r\n')
fs.appendFile('msgs.json', logger, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
})
```